# Unable to merge two dataframes using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Despite multiple attempts I am not succeeding in doing a simple merge operation on two dataframes. Below code returns

> KeyError: 'CODE'

on the merge function.
Note 1: To make the post reproducible, StringIO is used here with only two lines within each CSV, but in real life I read from files with thousands of records.
Note 2: Notice the trailing ',' (separator) at the end of each line: my CSV files are badly formatted but this is how actual files are.
Note 3: I am using Python 2.7

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

master = StringIO("""N-NUMBER,SERIAL NUMBER,MFR MDL CODE,ENG MFR MDL,YEAR MFR,TYPE REGISTRANT,NAME,STREET,STREET2,CITY,STATE,ZIP CODE,REGION,COUNTY,COUNTRY,LAST ACTION DATE,CERT ISSUE DATE,CERTIFICATION,TYPE AIRCRAFT,TYPE ENGINE,STATUS CODE,MODE S CODE,FRACT OWNER,AIR WORTH DATE,OTHER NAMES(1),OTHER NAMES(2),OTHER NAMES(3),OTHER NAMES(4),OTHER NAMES(5),EXPIRATION DATE,UNIQUE ID,KIT MFR, KIT MODEL,MODE S CODE HEX,
1    ,1071                          ,3980115,54556,1988,5,FEDERAL AVIATION ADMINISTRATION                   ,WASHINGTON REAGAN NATIONAL ARPT  ,3201 THOMAS AVE HANGAR 6         ,WASHINGTON        ,DC,20001     ,1,001,US,20160614,19900214,1T        ,5,5 ,V ,50000001, ,19880909,                                                  ,                                                  ,                                                  ,                                                  ,                                                  ,20191130,00524101,                              ,                    ,A00001    ,""")

mfr = StringIO("""CODE,MFR,MODEL,TYPE-ACFT,TYPE-ENG,AC-CAT,BUILD-CERT-IND,NO-ENG,NO-SEATS,AC-WEIGHT,SPEED,
3980115,EXLINE ACE-C                  ,ACE-C               ,4,1 ,1,1,01,001,CLASS 1,0082,""")

masterdf = pd.read_csv(master,sep=",",index_col=False)
mfrdf = pd.read_csv(mfr,sep=",",index_col=False)

masterdf.merge(mfrdataframe,left_on='MFR MDL CODE',right_on='CODE', how='inner')
```

Comment: In your presented code, on the merge line change 'mfrdataframe' to 'mfrdf'.  Once I mad that change on the last line it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is the name of the dataframe you're passing to `merge`: `mfrdataframe` should instead be `mfrdf`.